# I want to store input data in object but can't be able to do so?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

**html**

```
<form name="AdminForm" onsubmit="return Updateit()">
      <input type="text" id="name" required>
      <input type="email" id="email" required>
      <input type="number" id="phoneNumb" required>
      <input type="text" id="address" required>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
var database = {}
function Updateit(){
    const Name = document.forms["AdminForm"]["name"].value;
    const Email = document.forms["AdminForm"]["email"].value;
    const PhoneNumb = document.forms["AdminForm"]["phoneNumb"].value;
    const Address = document.forms["AdminForm"]["address"].value;

    database[Name] = [Email,PhoneNumb.toString(),Address];
    console.log(database[Name]);
}
```

**the data in object is vanished after a Millisecond**
*After input data in form i used to save that data in database object but is not shown in it when i try to display in console or alert.*

Comment: Maybe because, on form submission, the form went away and you lost the fields? You are not describing the full-scope of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified your Html structure and when this function was triggered, but if so, what is the problem with its operation ?

```js
var database = {}

let button = document.getElementById("get-form");
button.addEventListener("click", Updateit)

function Updateit() {
  const Name = document.forms["AdminForm"]["name"].value;
  const Email = document.forms["AdminForm"]["email"].value;
  const PhoneNumb = document.forms["AdminForm"]["phoneNumb"].value;
  const Address = document.forms["AdminForm"]["address"].value;

  database[Name] = [Email, PhoneNumb.toString(), Address];
  console.log(database[Name]);
}
```

```html
<form name="AdminForm">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="email" name="email">
  <input type="text" name="phoneNumb">
  <input type="text" name="address">
  <button type="button" id="get-form">Get Form Items</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var database = {}

    database.Name = document.forms["AdminForm"]["name"].value;
    database.Email = document.forms["AdminForm"]["email"].value;
    database.PhoneNumb = document.forms["AdminForm"]["phoneNumb"].value;
    database.Address = document.forms["AdminForm"]["address"].value;
function Updateit(){
    console.log(database[Name]);
}
}
```